# cfn-signal UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and cannot be signaled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Sometimes, the command cfn-signal is crashing with this message:

> ValidationError: Stack
>   arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:XXXXX:stack/XXX/XXXXX
>   is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and cannot be signaled

With this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 \ 
  --stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:XXX:stack/XXX/XXXX \
  --resource AutoScalingGroup \
  --region eu-west-1
```

I don't understand why the CloudFormation state is related? I believe it's the AutoScalingGroup that is waiting for the life cycle event?

When I manually complete the instance life cycle, there is no issue:

```
aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action \
  --auto-scaling-group-name XXXX \
  --lifecycle-hook-name CodeDeploy-managed-automatic-launch-deployment-hook-XX \
  --instance-id i-XX \
  --lifecycle-action-result CONTINUE \
  --region eu-west-1
```

Part of the UserData script:

```
 UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      [...]
      # Setup CodeDeploy
      sudo /home/ubuntu/install-codedeploy-agent auto
      rm /home/ubuntu/install-codedeploy-agent

      # Install the files and packages from the metadata
      /usr/local/bin/cfn-init -v \
        --stack ${AWS::StackId} \
        --resource LaunchConfiguration \
        --region ${AWS::Region}

      # All done so signal success to CloudFormation
      /usr/local/bin/cfn-signal -e $? \
        --stack ${AWS::StackId} \
        --resource AutoScalingGroup \
        --region ${AWS::Region}

      # Start CodeDeploy agent
      sudo service codedeploy-agent start
      sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

The AutoScaling Group definition:

```
AutoScalingGroup:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZones:
      Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region
    LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref LaunchConfiguration
    MinSize: 1
    MaxSize: 2
    DesiredCapacity: 1
    TargetGroupARNs:
      - !Ref ElasticLoadBalancerTargetGroup
    HealthCheckType: ELB
    HealthCheckGracePeriod: 600 # in seconds
  CreationPolicy:
    ResourceSignal:
      Count: 1
      Timeout: PT15M # 15 minutes
  UpdatePolicy:
    AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
      PauseTime: PT15M # 15 minutes
      WaitOnResourceSignals: true
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `cfn-signal` is completely unrelated to autoscaling lifecycle hooks.

Its purpose is to signal CloudFormation that instances in a given autoscaling group are ready. When a definite number of success signal is received by CloudFormation it will consider the ASG is `CREATE_COMPLETE` or `UPDATE_COMPLETE`. If the stack that is supposed to receive the signals has rolled back because of some other problems in the template, `cfn-signal` will fail as its signal is no longer relevant for stack in a `_COMPLETE` status.

Comment: ok! Thanks a lot. The issue is because I read that I should start the codedeploy agent after cfn-signal. So should I ignore all the crash of cfn-signal or should I start the codedeploy agent before cfn-signal?

Comment: To help you I would need to know why the stack is in the `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` state.

Comment: It happens also with UPDATE_COMPLETE and CREATE_COMPLETE state as you stated in your answer but fyi, the stack had an issue resolved by now. I added a part of the UserData script in my question.

Comment: Can you add the autoscaling group definition as well ? Because cfn-signal as to work in concert with a `CreationPolicy`.

Comment: I added the auto scaling group definition.

Comment: Have you checked my asg definition?